# Get 3 years ago timestamp in golang?

Tags: time, go, unix-timestamp

I want to get the time unix time stamp 3 years ago, I use this now:

```
time.Now().Unix(() - 3 * 3600 * 24 * 365
```

This is not that accurate anyway (because year may have 366 days).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Simply use the [`Time.AddDate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate) method where you can specify the time to add in years, months and days, all of which can also be negative if you want to go back in time:

`AddDate()` method declaration:

```
func (t Time) AddDate(years int, months int, days int) Time
```

Example:

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t)
t2 := t.AddDate(-3, 0, 0)
fmt.Println(t2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/eNSqOcBkUJ)):

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
2006-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: Careful, you're not taking care of the leap year.
```2024-02-29 -3 years is 2021-03-01. ```
Guess why i'm posting it today lol

Comment: @TommasoResti I think that's exactly the correct result. There is no `2021-02-29`, the day after `2021-02-28` is `2021-03-01`.

Comment: True. I can share the use case that didn't work in my case. I needed the same bimonthly period (January 1st to February 28th) from years before. Doing 28/02/2000 - 2 years works in most of the cases. But when the actual period ends is 29/02/20XX then you've a problem. So the thing is careful if, by subtracting the year, you expect the same day and month.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func timeShift(now time.Time, timeType string, shift int) time.Time {
    var shiftTime time.Time
    switch timeType {
    case "year":
        shiftTime = now.AddDate(shift, 0, 0)
    case "month":
        shiftTime = now.AddDate(0, shift, 0)
    case "day":
        shiftTime = now.AddDate(0, 0, shift)
    case "hour":
        shiftTime = now.Add(time.Hour * time.Duration(shift))
    case "minute":
        shiftTime = now.Add(time.Minute * time.Duration(shift))
    case "second":
        shiftTime = now.Add(time.Second * time.Duration(shift))
    default:
        shiftTime = now
    }
    return shiftTime
}

func main(){
    d := time.Now().UTC()
    fmt.Println(timeShift(d, "month", 1))
    fmt.Println(timeShift(d, "day", -1))
    fmt.Println(timeShift(d, "hour", -1))
    fmt.Println(timeShift(d, "minute", -1))
    fmt.Println(timeShift(d, "second", -1))
}
```

Comment: So you're saying, to adjust the "now" by a "shift" number of years:
`now.AddDate(shift, 0, 0)`

The current time can be adjusted to @roger's three years previous with your function using the following:
`timeShift(time.Now(), year, -3)`

Comment: Same as @icza's answer. You don't take care of leap years